# Collections in Scala class

Tags: scala

how do I init collections in a Scala class like "null"?
For example

```
class Plopp(val name: String, var multiline: mutable.Set[String])
```

And in that class I want to define an aditional contructor like

```
def this(name: String) = this(name, null)
```

Everywhere I look there just examples with simple types like String, Int aso.

**Update due to the answer:**

```
class Plopp(val name: String, var multiline: Option[Set[String]] = None)
```

Comment: What is your question? You already define a class and an additional constructor. What else do you want?

Comment: How do I initialize that Set[String]? As far as I know there is no "null" in Scala.

Comment: Yes, there is `null` in Scala, and your code is complete (that is, if you paste `def this(..)` inside `class Plopp(...) { /* HERE */ }`

Comment: Ah okay! To be honest I didn't try that. Can you write that as an answer so that I can close that question? Thanks!

Comment: There is null, but the best practice is not using it.  You should use Option instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala has inherited `null` from Java, so you can write basically what you did in your question:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

class Plopp(val name: String, var multiline: mutable.Set[String]) {
  def this(name: String) = this(name,null)
}
```

*Whether this makes sense* is a different question:

- you are using a `var` for a mutable collection. you probably want either a `val` here (because you mutate the collection in place), or you change to an immutable collection
- you should avoid `null` in Scala. There are better abstractions for signalising optional values, in particular `Option`.
- perhaps you can also find a sensible other value in place of `null` here, for example the empty collection.
- overriding methods and constructors is usually considered bad style. Note that you can also use default values. Here is a suggestion: `case class Plopp(name: String, multiline: Set[String] = Set.empty)` (implying `collection.immutable.Set`).